# Laravel 5.1 debugbar not showing in virtual host

Tags: laravel-5.1, phpdebugbar

I installed fresh laravel 5.1
Added 
Debugbar from this
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
Its working fine in localhost/laravel/public but not working in virtual host like http://laravel.dev
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Ad blocker Plugin on browser :)